# how to load selected contacts into recycle view ? by using broakenmedia / MultiContactPicker dependency

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

i am using https://github.com/broakenmedia/MultiContactPicker

this is a code ..

```
new MultiContactPicker.Builder(MainActivity.this) //Activity/fragment context
                            .theme(R.style.MyCustomPickerTheme) //Optional - default: MultiContactPicker.Azure
                            .hideScrollbar(false) //Optional - default: false
                            .showTrack(true) //Optional - default: true
                            .searchIconColor(Color.WHITE) //Option - default: White
                            .setChoiceMode(MultiContactPicker.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE) //Optional - default: CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE
                            .handleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary)) //Optional - default: Azure Blue
                            .bubbleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary)) //Optional - default: Azure Blue
                            .bubbleTextColor(Color.WHITE) //Optional - default: White
                            .setTitleText("Select Contacts") //Optional - default: Select Contacts
                            .setSelectedContacts("10", "5" / myList) //Optional - will pre-select contacts of your choice. String... or List<ContactResult>
                            .setLoadingType(MultiContactPicker.LOAD_ASYNC) //Optional - default LOAD_ASYNC (wait till all loaded vs stream results)
                            .limitToColumn(LimitColumn.NONE) //Optional - default NONE (Include phone + email, limiting to one can improve loading time)
                            .setActivityAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out,
                                    android.R.anim.fade_in,
                                    android.R.anim.fade_out) //Optional - default: No animation overrides
                            .showPickerForResult(CONTACT_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

Then listen for results:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == CONTACT_PICKER_REQUEST){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            List<ContactResult> results = MultiContactPicker.obtainResult(data);
            Log.d("MyTag", results.get(0).getDisplayName());
        } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            System.out.println("User closed the picker without selecting items.");
        }
    }
}
```

i want load selected contact into recycle view

Comment: this is my adapter class

Answer (score 0):

this is my adapter class

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.viewHolder> {
    ArrayList<ContactResult> list;
    Context context;

    public ContactAdapter(ArrayList<ContactResult> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_contact,parent,false);
        return new ContactAdapter.viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
        ContactResult model = list.get(position);
        holder.contactName.setText(model.getDisplayName());
     //   holder.contactNumber.setText(model.getPhoneNumbers());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView contactName;
  //      TextView contactNumber;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            contactName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
    //        contactNumber= itemView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_no);
        }
    }
}
```

error:

2021-02-11 10:34:53.566 20092-20092/com.example.womensafety E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false

help me plz